# How to overwrite a file correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know how to overwrite a file in python. When I'm using `"w"` in the `open` statement, I still get only one line in my output file.

```
article = open("article.txt", "w")
article.write(str(new_line))
article.close()
```

Can you tell me please how can I fix my problem?

Comment: Why do you think there's a problem? If you're overwriting the file, there *should* only be one line in the output. If you want to *`a`dd* to the file, why open it in over`w`rite mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in fact looking to *overwrite* the file line by line, you'll have to do some additional work - since the only modes available are `r`ead ,`w`rite and `a`ppend, neither of which actually do a line-by-line overwrite.

See if this is what you're looking for:

```
# Write some data to the file first.
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for s in ['This\n', `is a\n`, `test\n`]:
        f.write(s)

# The file now looks like this:
# file.txt
# >This
# >is a
# >test

# Now overwrite

new_lines = ['Some\n', 'New data\n']
with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
    # Get the previous contents
    lines = f.readlines()

    # Overwrite
    for i in range(len(new_lines)):
        f.write(new_lines[i])
    if len(lines) > len(new_lines):
        for i in range(len(new_lines), len(lines)):
            f.write(lines[i])
```

As you can see, you first need to 'save' the contents of the file in a buffer (`lines`), and then replace that.

The reason for that [is how the file modes work.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)

Comment: Thank you four your Code-Example. It inspired me very much. Now I know the solution for my problem!

Answer (score 0):

"overwrite" is a strange term;  especially since you expect to see more than one line from the above code

I am guessing you mean something like "write beyond".  The word for that would be "append' and you would want 'a' instead of 'w'.